# Sporadic messages output to console after logging in

Tags: startup, apparmor, ubuntu-minimal, rsyslog, wicd

Coming right from a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 Minimal/Netboot (plus some small utilities like `acpid`, `wicd-curses`, etc.), after logging in, I occasionally get floating messages (the kind typically seen in the bootup sequence) like the following:

```
randy@leviathan:~$  * Starting AppArmor profiles
Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslog

* Setting up X socket directories...                                    [OK]
* Starting Network connection manager wicd                              [OK]
* Restoring resolver state...                                           [OK]
```

Where do these floating messages come from? And how can one remove them?

Answer (score 1):

These are boot messages, which as you can see report processes and services being started. Typically, you can find them for troubleshooting in `/var/log/boot.log` after you booted and logged in. Now, it is unclear *why* you are getting them after logging in, but what you can do is the following workaround: add `reset` command to the end of your `.bashrc` file, which will clear and reset the terminal each time you login